# How do you correctly filter links using .find in a for loop with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new at programing so I am trying to start simple. I want to make a web scraper that will, when given a Wikipedia site, store the heading and the first paragraph of every article linked in that page.  Im in the beginning where I want to select the links and filter for the ones with "/wiki/" in them. Here is what I have so far, sorry if it's painfully wrong:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrapeWikiArticle(url):
    response = requests.get(
        url=url,
    )

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="firstHeading")
    #first print selected subject
    print(title.text)

    allLinks = soup.find(id="bodyContent").find_all("a")
    allLinks_len = len(allLinks)

    for link in allLinks:
        # We are only interested in other wiki articles
        if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1:

            for i in range(allLinks_len):
                print(allLinks[i])
        break

scrapeWikiArticle("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
```

My output includes href's without /wiki in them so that is not working. I also assume that the range attribute is wrong because allLinks_len will be longer after selecting for only links with /wiki/ in them.

Seems to me like `if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1:` should go in the `for i in range(allLinks_len):` loop but that gives me:

```
if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

It's likely I'm going about this from the wrong angle entirely. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.
This is my first question on stack overflow, I hope it's written ok. Constructive criticism welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_wiki_articles(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="firstHeading")
    print(title.text)

    for link in soup.find(id="bodyContent").find_all("a"):
        if "/wiki/" not in link['href']:
            print(link['href'])


scrape_wiki_articles("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping")
```

Output:

```
#cite_ref-1
http://www.searchenginehistory.com/
#cite_ref-2
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4fb4/3c5a212df751e84c3b2f8d29fabfe56c3616.pdf
#cite_ref-3
http://www.gooseeker.com/en/node/knowledgebase/freeformat
#cite_ref-4
http://www.xconomy.com/san-francisco/2012/07/25/diffbot-is-using-computer-vision-to-reinvent-the-semantic-web/
#cite_ref-5
https://web.archive.org/web/20020308222536/http://www.chillingeffects.org/linking/faq.cgi#QID596
http://www.chillingeffects.org/linking/faq.cgi#QID596
and so on...
```

Output:

Comment: That's it! And so much more clearly written. In my case I'm selecting for the /wiki/ so I just removed the 'not' from the if loop. Much appreciated.

Comment: Soon after I found there are <a> tags without href tags gumming the works, so i added href=True to the find_all element.